# Show single dropdown for combined month and year in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there a way to show a single dropdown list in the datepicker that displays both the month and the year (e.g. "November 2012") instead of separate dropdown lists (using changeMonth: true, changeYear: true).

Comment: Not a good idea. Separate dropdowns take up much less space and are far more efficient.

Comment: I think it will depend on the use of your calendar. If you check most online travel websites that is how the show the month and year selection. Our business is in a hotel and it will be very helpful with our client if we are gonna show them less options.